# Syntax error in trigger function with 'update' statement - PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, psql

I created a table equipment_rented:

```
CREATE TABLE equipment_rented
(
    rental_id int NOT NULL,
    equipment_id int NOT NULL,
    quantity int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(rental_id, equipment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(rental_id) REFERENCES rentals(rental_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(equipment_id) REFERENCES equipment(equipment_id)
);
```

I tried to create a trigger that, when a record is added or updated to a table `equipment_rented`, will update (decrease) the available quantity in another table - equipment (details below).

```
CREATE TABLE equipment
(
    equipment_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id int NOT NULL,
    brand_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    model_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    daily_rate int NOT NULL,
    quantity_available int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(category_id)
);
```

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER decrease_available_quantity_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON equipment_rented
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_available_quantity_func();
```

I tried to create a trigger function but PSQL still returns an error and I can't find the reason.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "quantity_available"
> LINE 22: SET SET quantity_available = current_quantity

The function I wanted to create:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_available_quantity_func() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
DECLARE
    difference INT;
    current_quantity INT;
    record RECORD;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        difference := 0 - NEW.quantity;

    ELSE
        difference := OLD.quantity - NEW.quantity;
    END IF;
    SELECT quantity_available + difference INTO current_quantity FROM equipment
    WHERE equipment_id = NEW.equipment_id;
        
    IF current_quantity < 0 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'quantity_available cannot be negative. equipment_id = %, current_quantity = %', NEW.equipment_id, current_quantity;

    ELSE
        UPDATE equipment
        SET quantity_available = current_quantity
        WHERE equipment_id = NEW.equipment_id;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Updated equipment_id = %, current quantity = %', NEW.equipment_id, (SELECT quantity_available FROM equipment WHERE equipment_id = NEW.equipment_id);
    END IF;

RETURN NEW; 
    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

So currently I'm stuck at the stage of creating the function and I don't know what I should change to make it work.

I tried to update the table 'Equipment' without any function and it worked correctly.
I also checked whether there are some typos, but I don't see any.

I'm out of ideas what could be wrong with quantity_available column in 'update' statement.

I also tried to create a simpler version of this function (+with and without 'from NEW' in update statement) and still returns the same error:
*syntax error at or near "quantity_available"
LINE 4: SET SET quantity_available = quantity_available - NEW.quanti...*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decrease_available_quantity_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN   
    UPDATE equipment
    SET quantity_available = quantity_available - NEW.quantity
    WHERE equipment_id = NEW.equipment_id;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Updated equipment_id = %, current quantity = %', NEW.equipment_id, (SELECT quantity_available FROM equipment WHERE equipment_id = NEW.equipment_id);

return NEW;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The error is `...SET SET quantity_available...` so it looks like whatever function is actually being run has `UPDATE equipment  SET   SET quantity_available = current_quantity ...`.  In `psql` use `\ef function_name` to see what is actually in the function.

Comment: O.O whaat;
I removed 'SET' from my statements and now it works. :O
It's weird, but thank you so much @AdrianKlaver

Comment: If you are talking about the `SET` in `SET quantity_available = ...` then something is wrong. Best guess is there is a `SET` out of frame in whatever you are viewing the code in.

Comment: Yes, I agree that something is wrong. When I check my function using '\ef', the SET is there.

Comment: 1) `SET` is where? 2) Do you have more then one version of the function, maybe in different schema?

Comment: 1) SET is in my function source code when I check it using \ef function_name although I removed it when I was creating a function ; 2) I have only one version of this function.